# Asp.net web application compiling, but not launching the browser when the application is run (VS 2010)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a Web Application that I received from another developer, when I first opened the solution in Visual Studio 2010, it gave a message that the URL for the application has not been created in IIS and do I want Visual Studio to set up a virtual folder. I clicked "yes", and in the IIS manager I see that the virtual folder has been created. I also went to directory security for the virtual folder and enabled *integrated windows authentication*.

The problem is that when I try launch the application, changes to "running", but a browser windows is not opened and if I look in *inetpub\wwwroot* I do not see a folder for my application. Another thing I noticed, is that in the properties for the virtual folder in IIS, under the tab ASP.Net, there is a dropdown box called *ASP.Net version*; this dropdown box only has options 2.0.50727 and 4.0.30319 whereas the application that I am trying to launch is targetting .Net framework 3.5. The .Net framework 3.5 is installed on the computer so I have no idea why it is not being shown in this dropdown box. Maybe it is relevant to the problem I am experiencing?? The IIS version running on my computer is IIS 6.

Does anyone know what could be going wrong here and how I can fix it? Thanks.

EDIT: Ok. Now I am a step further. I have changed the *start action* under the *Web* section of the solution properties to be *Specific page: Default.aspx*; this setting was on *Don't open a page*. (Thanks, anirudh4444 for this info). Now the browser opens when I click run, and I briefly see it attempting to go to the correct url (namely, *http://localhost/ripcord/default.aspx*), but it immediately changes to *http://www.ripcord.co.za/default.aspx*, which is the site where this project was previously hosted. It then displays "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." If I manually put in the local url then I get a popup box showing asking me for a username and password.

EDIT 2: I added a stack trace here, but have removed it because it is not relevant to the problem that I am encountering. This stack trace, I have determined, is actually showing an exception occurring on the remote site. My problem is that when I try and navigate to *http://localhost/ripcord* that it is redirecting to the remote site. I am needing to stop it doing that and instead execute the application locally.

Comment: 3.5 are extensions to the 2.0 runtime, 4.0 is a new runtime.

Comment: Right click on your project in the solution explorer, and change the start options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirection can occur in several places: the web.config settings (like an  in a  tag), in IIS configuration, in the project settings (like start up behavior), or in code.

Do a search in your code and config files to find 'http://www.ripcord.co.za' to see if it is your code. Then look at IIS settings.

Answer (score 0):

What does the customErrors in your Web.config look like?  Does it use a relative path or an absolute path?

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/errors/GeneralError.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/errors/PageNotFound.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

If an exception is thrown and not handled, the custom errors will use the redirect settings